# Rename directories from "fname [mname] lname" to "lname, fname [mname]"

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have a bunch of directories with author's names as "first [mi] last" (middle initial/name could be multiples), and I'd like to change them to "last, first mi". So I'd like a way to parse the name into multiple tokens, then rearrange the tokens.

In `awk`, it would be something like:

```
ls | awk print '$NF", "  $1,$2 ...'
```

Comment: Unless you know all the last names are one word only it's most likely an impossible task... How could a script determine that _Johannes Diderik van der Waals_' last name is _van der Waals_ and not _Waals_ ?

Comment: Notwithstanding the constraints noted by @don_crissti, my go-to for this kind of thing would be the perl-based `rename`/`prename` command - does your system have it?

Comment: @don_crissti: Thanks, I hadn't considered that, and I think you're right.  But for my case, it won't really matter, as I can handle a few (if any) exceptions by hand.  I just want to avoid renaming all of them by hand.  So, even if I only automate 75%, it's a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and be shell-agnostic, run it as a script with a single parameter which is your base directory.

1. It uses `find` to get the names of directories one per line, assuming they are located immediately below the supplied base directory and excluding any that have already been converted.
2. It uses `awk` to strip the base directory from the list, leaving on each line just the name of the immediate directory which is the one you want to change. (`awk` here uses / as a field delimiter and prints the last field on each line.)
3. It uses `awk` a second time to print out a `mv` command to rename each of these directories in the way you requested. (`awk` here uses the default whitespace as a field delimiter.)
4. Save the output to a file and then execute it when you are satisfied it looks right.

.

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "*,*"|\
awk -F/ '{print $NF}'|\
awk -v DIR="$1" '{printf "mv \"" DIR "/" $0 "\" \"" DIR "/" $NF", "; for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {printf $i" "}; printf "\"\n"}'
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work well.  I don't know awk very well, so I'll play around with it to make sure I understand the details so I'll learn a bit, but the listing looks great.